# How do I find out the audio access unit duration from MP3 files?

Tags: mp3

This is defined in ISO/IEC 13818-3 as:

2.1.10  audio access unit [audio]: For Layers I and II, an audio access unit is defined as the smallest part of the encoded bit stream which can be decoded by itself, where decoded means "fully reconstructed sound". **For Layer III, an audio access unit is part of the bit stream that is decodable with the use of previously acquired main information**

How can I determine the duration of audio access units in any given MP3 file?